# How to memorize data that was entered in form before it was submitted

Tags: php, html, forms

I came across the problem, I use re-captcha to validate user input. I made it so if wrong captcha was entered it displays an error message. It works fine, but once user submits form it reloads the page to show an error message, because of this all data entered by user gets lost. Is there a way to memorize what user entered before, so the only thing they need to change is a captcha text?

Here is the page: http://inelmo.com/create_story.php
submit a form with wrong captcha to see an error message and you will see that all data gets lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try settings the values for the inputs. So something like `<input type="text" name="something" value="<?php echo $_POST['something'];?>">`

Comment: be sure to test such a solution thoroughly, directly entering $_POST data in your output can have (dangerous) side effects. For instance, if the user entered a " symbol in the input field 'something', it can mess up the generated HTML if the symbols are not properly escaped.

Comment: @catchmeifyoutry However, escaping symbols and displaying them in a value of a textbox will sometimes be misleading. Although I do understand your point

Comment: Yeh I will now, had to wait 5 min before I could accept it )))

Answer (score 0):

To combat this (as well as to allow PHP-validation to work for JS disabled users) I often use:

```
<input type="text" id="whatever" name="whatever" value="<?= $_POST['whatever']; ?> />
```

This way, any submitted data will be returned. :)

Answer (score 0):

As the form was submitted to the PHP script you already have access to all they information which they provided. It is simply a case of `echo`ing the POST data into the markup.